# Como alterar uma list view a partir de uma Combo no VB6

Tags: listview, visual-basic-6, combobox

Fiz um formulário com uma `ListView` e uma `ComboBox`, meu problema é que de acordo com o que é selecionado na `ComboBox` tenho que alterar os dados da `ListView`.

Por exemplo: Tenho a `ListView` LETRAS(que já é carregada com valores no `Load_Form`) e uma combo Tipo(consoantes e vogais), se na combo eu selecionar 'vogais' tem que aparecer 'a,e,i,o,u' na `ListView`.

Comment: Você chegou a tentar utilizar o evento [`Click`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/285371/2896619) do `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve utilizar os eventos da combo box para isso.
Crie um método para popular a listview tipo

```
Private Sub PopularListView(ByVal letra As String)
    'Adicionar as linhas conforme a letra passada por parâmetro
End Sub
```

Depois, chame este método no evento Change da combobox:

```
Private Sub Combo_Change()
    Call PopularListView(Combo.Text)
End Sub
```

A grosso modo é isso.